# How to dynamically generate marshmallow schemas for SQLAlchemy models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm creating a Flask API using SQLAlchemy models.
I don't want to define a schema for every model I have, I don't want to do this every time:

```
class EntrySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

I would like each model to have a schema, so it can easily dump itself.
Creating a default Schema and setting the Schema.Meta.model didn't work:

```
class Entry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    started_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    ended_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    description = db.Column(db.Text())

    def __init__(self, data):
        for key in data:
            setattr(self, key, data[key])

        self.Schema = Schema
        self.Schema.Meta.model = self.__class__

    def dump(self):
        schema = self.Schema()
        result = schema.dump(self)
        return result


class Schema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        pass
```

Why is a generic Schema with the model overwritten different than a Schema with the model declared?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could create a class decorator that adds the `Schema` to your models:

```
def add_schema(cls):
    class Schema(ma.ModelSchema):
        class Meta:
            model = cls
    cls.Schema = Schema
    return cls
```

and then

```
@add_schema
class Entry(db.Model):
    ...
```

The schema will be available as the class attribute `Entry.Schema`.

The reason your original attempt fails is that marshmallow `Schema` classes are constructed using a [custom metaclass](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/dev/marshmallow/schema.py#L74), which inspects the namespace created from executing the class body and [does its thing](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/blob/dev/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py#L86). When you modify the already constructed class, it is too late.

If you're unfamiliar with metaclasses in Python, read about them in the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses). They are a tool that allows for great things and great misuse.

---

Some more complex types, such as enums, require additional information and dedicated field types to work properly. For example [using marshmallow-enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717768/how-to-serialise-a-enum-property-in-sqlalchemy-using-marshmallow) and a decorator factory pattern it is possible to configure the model schema to accommodate enums:

```
from marshmallow_enum import EnumField

def add_schema(**kwgs):
    def decorator(cls): 
        class Meta:
            model = cls

        schema = type("Schema", (ma.ModelSchema,), {"Meta": Meta, **kwgs})
        cls.Schema = schema
        return cls

    return decorator

...


@add_schema(
    my_enum=EnumField(MyEnumType, by_value=True)
)
class Entry(db.Model):
    ...
```

Of course another way would be to [make the decorator itself smarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697476/generating-marshmallow-schema-automatically-with-json-serializable-enums) and inspect the class before building the schema, so that it handles special cases such as enums.

Comment: Can you do it without sqlalchemy? I have some denormalized classes with lists in them but sqlalchemy does not allow lists.

Comment: UPD: found [this project](https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass) that uses Python's dataclasses instead of sqlalchemy.
And even more syntax sugar!

Comment: if the model has an Enum, an error will be thrown: `Object of type MyEnum is not JSON serializable` upon dumping

Comment: @jgozal That is unfortunate, but not strictly related to the decoration itself, but to how marshmallow works – and I am not that familiar with it in the end. If it requires extra information to make it correctly serialize enums, you would then turn `add_schema` to a decorator factory that accepts the necessary arguments, and returns the "configured" decorator closure.

Comment: @jgozal Added an example of the above.

Comment: thanks @IljaEverilä. This is a solid solution. I'm working on a way to find the enums in the schema by looking at the _declared_fields after the schema is created and then turning each of them into marshmallow enum fields dynamically. I'll let you know if I can make it work! I posted a question here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697476/generating-marshmallow-schema-automatically-with-json-serializable-enums

Comment: @jgozal If you are taking the inspection route, I highly recommend using the [runtime inspection API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/inspection.html) and tools, instead of accessing the protected attributes directly (though, is `_declared_fields` a marshmallow thing?).

Comment: @IljaEverilä I believe `_declared_fields` is a marshmallow thing, but it's still a protected attribute? I've come up with a more dynamic solution, please see my answer in the question I referenced in my earlier comment. I'd love to get your thoughts, and you can hopefully help me improve it as well.

Comment: Usually the `_` is used to indicate that an attribute is an implementation detail, and should not be relied on, but sometimes you cannot help it.

Answer (score 2):

**From marshmallow-sqlalchemy recipes:**

> "Automatically Generating Schemas For SQLAlchemy Models It can be
>   tedious to implement a large number of schemas if not overriding any
>   of the generated fields as detailed above. SQLAlchemy has a hook that
>   can be used to trigger the creation of the schemas, assigning them to
>   the SQLAlchemy model property ".

My example using flask_sqlalchemy & marshmallow_sqlalchemy:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelConversionError, ModelSchema
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper


db = SQLAlchemy()


def setup_schema(Base, session):
    # Create a function which incorporates the Base and session information
    def setup_schema_fn():
        for class_ in Base._decl_class_registry.values():
            if hasattr(class_, "__tablename__"):
                if class_.__name__.endswith("Schema"):
                    raise ModelConversionError(
                        "For safety, setup_schema can not be used when a"
                        "Model class ends with 'Schema'"
                    )

                class Meta(object):
                    model = class_
                    sqla_session = session

                schema_class_name = "%sSchema" % class_.__name__

                schema_class = type(schema_class_name, (ModelSchema,), {"Meta": Meta})

                setattr(class_, "Schema", schema_class)

    return setup_schema_fn


event.listen(mapper, "after_configured", setup_schema(db.Model, db.session))
```

There is another example in the recipes:

https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#automatically-generating-schemas-for-sqlalchemy-models

Comment: A really nice approach, and a good example of SQLA events in general.

Answer (score 1):

The [marshmallow recipes](http://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html) prescribe a couple of alternative options for throwing common schema options into a base class. Here's a quick example straight from the docs:

```
# myproject/schemas.py

from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema

from .db import Session

class BaseSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        sqla_session = Session
```

and then extend the base schema:

```
# myproject/users/schemas.py

from ..schemas import BaseSchema
from .models import User

class UserSchema(BaseSchema):

    # Inherit BaseSchema's options
    class Meta(BaseSchema.Meta):
        model = User
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can add more de/serialization to specific models

More examples and recipes on the linked docs