# Dynamically generating marshmallow schemas for SQLAlchemy fails on column attribute lookup for Relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy

I am automatically deriving marshmallow schemas for SQLAlchemy objects using the approach described in [How to dynamically generate marshmallow schemas for SQLAlchemy models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891152/how-to-dynamically-generate-marshmallow-schemas-for-sqlalchemy-models).

I am then decorating my model classes:

```py
@derive_schema
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=sqlalchemy.text("uuid_generate_v4()"))
    name = db.Column(String, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


@derive_schema
class FooSettings(db.Model):
    foo_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('foo.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    my_settings = db.Column(JSONB, nullable=True)
    foo = db.relationship('Foo', backref=db.backref('foo_settings'))
```

Where my `derive_schema` decorator is defined as follows:

```py
import marshmallow
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema

def derive_schema(cls):
    class Schema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
        class Meta:
            include_fk = True
            include_relationships = True
            load_instance = True
            model = cls

    marshmallow.class_registry.register(f'{cls.__name__}.Schema', Schema)
    cls.Schema = Schema
    return cls
```

This used to work fine with SQLAlchemy 1.4. While attempting to upgrade to 2.0.3, I am running into the following exception when changing my schema to inherit `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` instead of `ModelSchema`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    from foo.model import Foo, FooSettings
  File "foo/model.py", line 21, in <module>
    class SourceSettings(db.Model):
  File "schema_generation/__init__.py", line 18, in derive_schema
    class Schema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
  File "python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow/schema.py", line 121, in __new__
    klass._declared_fields = mcs.get_declared_fields(
  File "python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 91, in get_declared_fields
    fields.update(mcs.get_declared_sqla_fields(fields, converter, opts, dict_cls))
  File "python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema/sqlalchemy_schema.py", line 130, in get_declared_sqla_fields
    converter.fields_for_model(
  File "python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 141, in fields_for_model
    field = base_fields.get(key) or self.property2field(prop)
  File "python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 180, in property2field
    field_class = field_class or self._get_field_class_for_property(prop)
  File "python3.10/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 262, in _get_field_class_for_property
    column = prop.columns[0]
  File "python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1329, in __getattr__
    return self._fallback_getattr(key)
  File "python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1298, in _fallback_getattr
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: columns
```

Looking internally in the stacktrace, [it seems like the problem is here](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/blob/5e5488b3468f584c20a0983409f5be2e715c1301/src/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py#L271):

```
def _get_field_class_for_property(self, prop):
    if hasattr(prop, "direction"):
        field_cls = Related
    else:
        column = prop.columns[0]
        field_cls = self._get_field_class_for_column(column)
    return field_cls
```

There is a check for an attribute named `direction` which is specified on the SQLAlchemy `Relationship` object. However, this attribute seems to be dynamically loaded, which causes the conditional check to fail and fall back to `prop.columns[0]`. But since this object is a `Relationship` and not a `ColumnProperty` it has no `columns` attribute which causes the program to crash.

However, I have found a way to force load the `direction` property by adding the following code to the `derive_schema` method, before creating the generating `Schema` class:

```
import marshmallow
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyAutoSchema
from sqlalchemy import inspect


def derive_schema(cls):
    mapper = inspect(cls)
    _ = [_ for _ in mapper.relationships]

    class Schema(SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
        class Meta:
            include_fk = True
            include_relationships = True
            load_instance = True
            model = cls

    marshmallow.class_registry.register(f'{cls.__name__}.Schema', Schema)
    cls.Schema = Schema
    return cls
```

Enumerating the relationships and force loading them fixes the materialization of the `direction` property and thus the program loads fine.

Am I missing something in the model definition to make this work without force loading the relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a compatibility issue with SQLAlchemy 2.x.

- marshmallow-sqlalchemy 0.28 doesn't support SQLAlchemy 2.x but the "sqlalchemy<2.0" lock was only introduced in marshmallow-sqlalchemy 0.28.2 so before I released 0.28.2 people could end up with incompatible versions.
- marshmallow-sqlalchemy 0.29 supports SQLAlchemy 2.x and drops 1.3 support.

**TL;DR**

Update marshmallow-sqlalchemy and the issue should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy 2 is not officially supported by marshmallow-sqlalchemy at this moment.

Similar issues have been raised in the repository. [The following comment is most insightful in your context](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/issues/487#issuecomment-1433101988).

As stated in the above link, an implicit call to registry.configure() that was done in previous SQLAlchemy versions is now removed. You can achieve a similar result manually.

**After importing your models**:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import configure_mappers
configure_mappers()
```

Once you have imported the models, and called configure_mappers (in that order), you can import the schemas.

EDIT:

Refer to Jerome's comment below, and update to newest version as this has been patched.

Comment: Thank you! I saw the ticket a bit after I wrote this question and tried running `configure_mappers()` prior to calling the marshmallow-sqlalchemy code but it did not work, I still get the same error.

Comment: I added a comment on the issue: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/issues/487#issuecomment-1432660555

Comment: We may have a slightly different setup, on my side -- I setup the SQLAlchemy models separately, then call configure_mappers() and finally import schemas. If you call it too early it will not work as it needs the model relationships to be defined already.